# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error on installing app

Tags: android, xmpp

I am trying to install XMPP client on Android through adb install command but it gives INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES error, if anybody know about this error please help me

Please tell how test XMPP client on Android emulator.

Comment: People are less likely to help you if you don't accept their answers. Several of your other questions have valid (yet unaccepted) answers. That said, I'm not sure what to tell you. What XMPP client are you trying to install?

Comment: Trying to install Gtalk client

Comment: Details, brother! Which client - where did you get it, etc.

Comment: It's Android GTalk Client Application (Send/Receive XMPP Messages) , I got it in this link 
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/11/23/totally-unofficial-android-gtalk-client-sendreceive-xmpp-messages/

Comment: Hi Abhijit, I cant downlaod client from this link http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/11/23/totally-unofficial-android-gtalk-client-sendreceive-xmpp-messages/ Cuould make make avaiable to me that source becouse i am also working on Gtalk client and assume that code could help me . Thanks
Ijaz

Answer (score 1):

It seems your APK file is not signed.